# C++17 to_string() converts floats with comma

Tags: c++, string

This is happening inside a big project so I cannot really post a minimal reproducible example but I'll try asking anyway. I'm building a list of benchmarks application integrated with a framework we're working on and on one of them the convertion we require to make (float -> string) with `to_string` appears to reproduce a comma separated result.

```
| Monitored values:
| [ my_time_monitor.average = 61720,000000 ]
```

This is the function responsible:

```
std::string operating_point_parser::operator()(const int32_t num_threads, const float exec_time_ms) const {
    return "{\"compute\":[{\"knobs\":{\"num_threads\":" + std::to_string(num_threads) + "},\"metrics\":{\"exec_time_ms\":[" + std::to_string(exec_time_ms) + ",0]}}]}";
}
```

Since as I said the same exact function is being called by other applications which don't show this unexpected behavior, my guess is that some internal compilation flags are messing around.

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17 -DENABLE_THREADS  -DHAVE_RANDOM -DHAVE_UNISTD_H  -DHAVE_SYS_FILE_H -DHAVE_SYS_MMAN_H -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DVIPSDATASET_PATH=\"\\\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dataset/orion_18000x18000.v\\\"\"" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -DHAVE_RANDOM -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -DIM_PREFIX=\"\\\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dataset\\\"\" -DIM_EXEEXT=\"\\\"\\\"\" -DIM_LIBDIR=\"\\\"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib\\\"\" -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=\"\\\"vips7\"\\\" -DHAVE_SYS_FILE_H -DHAVE_SYS_MMAN_H -DHAVE_CONFIG_H")
```

If you want to take a look at the full application code here's the [link](https://bpa.st/3655M). The `operating_point_parse::operator()` is called inside `margot::compute::push_custom_monitor_values()`.

Comment: You may just need to set the correct locale: `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the Notes of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string, `to_string` relies on the **current locale** for formatting purposes:

> std::to_string relies on the current locale for formatting purposes,
> and therefore concurrent calls to std::to_string from multiple threads
> may result in partial serialization of calls. C++17 provides
> std::to_chars as a higher-performance locale-independent alternative.

So, if you want to have dots instead of commans, you have to adjust the current locale.

Or instead of changing the global locale with `std::locale::global(...)` you could use a `stringstream` and imbue() the locale on that stream only, for ex.

```
stringstream ss;
ss.imbue( locale you want )
ss << ... write what you need
ss.str(); // get formatted string
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::to_string` uses the currently active locale for formatting.

You can set the active locale using a C locale name using:

```
const char* locale = "C";
std::locale::global(std::locale(locale));
```

Meaning of locale name is specified in the C standard (quote from C11 draft):

> 7.11.1.1 The setlocale function
>
> A value of "C" for locale specifies the minimal environment for C translation; a value of "" for locale specifies the locale-specific native environment. Other implementation-defined strings may be passed as the second argument to setlocale.

---

> That value is going to be formatted inside a JSON string

In this case, and more generally when ever you wish to format using style that shouldn't depend on the global locale, should avoid `std::to_string`.

> What would you recommend since you advised on avoiding it?

Anything that doesn't use locale, or lets you specify the locale to use instead of using the global locale. For example:

```
std::format("{}", 0.42);                   // doesn't use locale
std::format(std::locale("C"), "{}", 0.42); // use specific locale
```

Another example is a stringstream with imbued locale as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks, I need to format using always the same locale. That value is going to be formatted inside a JSON string so using commas would affect the syntax.

Comment: @Barnercart If you're writing JSON, then you should not use `std::to_string`.

Comment: What would you recommend since you advised on avoiding it?

Comment: Don't need to pass locale to `std::format`. The latter is locale-independent unless the `L` format specifier is used.

Comment: @cpplearner Thanks. I've edited accordingly.